# select option hover is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, events

I wrote a little code to get some tooltips in my multiple select box,
The code is working file in FF but not in IE :(

ex:

```
$('#select > option').mouseover(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

onmouseover will not fire for option elements in Internet Explorer.  In fact, no mouse or keyboard events fire for option elements.  See the msdn documentation for the events available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(VS.85).aspx

**EDIT** - The same is true of Google Chrome (and most likely Safari too).

Comment: Is there anyway we can achive it ?? i want to fire some event on hover of select options. ????

Comment: @Tarun probably not, no. You'd likely have to build your own `<select>`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Pekka웃. yes i have my own select and i can get its onchage event also. But the code i have written for onmouseover for options is not working on chrome and other except FF. So is there any way we can dynamically put hover listener may be. actuly i want to get the hover index of currently hovered option of select box .. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tarun all the indication is that it's not possible. What I mean is that you'd probably have to rebuild `<select>` functionality in JavaScript, i.e. create a totally custom select widget (which comes with a host of issues and problems though). There are several such widgets in existence

Comment: @Pekka웃 can you share an example if that possible. i mean i tired many ways out but didnt get anything .. Thanks

Comment: @Tarun as said, there are several widgets out there, e.g. http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I can't guarantee that it makes hover work for `option`s, but try [**whatever:hover**](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html):

> Whatever:hover is a small script that automatically patches :hover, :active and :focus for IE6, IE7 and IE8 quirks, letting you use them like you would in any other browser. Version 3 introduces ajax support, meaning that any html that gets inserted into the document via javascript will also trigger :hover, :active and :focus styles in IE.

Comment: Its not setting tooltip only, i want to run some more scripts on hover event.

Comment: @Pekka웃 . but in this way we cant make a event listener for options. Do you have any other way out? Is it possible ..