# jQuery .hover function is not working on IE8(WinXP)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I got a problem in IE8(Win XP). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dTYfG/) is my code! My JQuery `.hover()` is not working on IE.

**SCRIPT**

```
$('select.lst option').hover(function(){            
        $(this).css('background-color','#EEE');            
    }
    ,function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#FFF');
    }
);
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="lst" id="lstCustomer" name="lstCustomer" size="4">
    <option value="11005100-17" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">คุณจิระ </option>

</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.lst {
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
height:150px;
width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detecting mouse events on option elements does not work in IE, as already discussed in this post:
[select option hover is not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064011/select-option-hover-is-not-working-in-ie)

I wouldn't recommend the use of a multiline select box in this case anyway, because select boxes also have limitations in the way you can use css to change their appearance - you can't change the background-colors of options using css, at least not in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think select option does not support this function.