# jQuery-Select list option hover

Tags: jquery

I want to alert an option when the mouse-cursor is over it. I use this code:

```
$("select > option").hover(function ()
    { 
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

Unfortunately, this is neither working in IE nor in FF.

Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: check the below links , useful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064011/select-option-hover-is-not-working-in-ie

Comment: one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$("select").hover(function (e)
{
     var $target = $(e.target); 
     if($target.is('option')){
         alert($target.attr("id"));//Will alert id if it has id attribute
         alert($target.text());//Will alert the text of the option
         alert($target.val());//Will alert the value of the option
     }
});
```

Comment: The reason being that Chrome and IE won't let you capture events directly on option elements, but do allow you to capture events on select elements.

Comment: I'm struggling with this for IE 8; I'm just not seeing mouseover or hoever events from the options, just the select.  Seems to work in Chrome and FF, but not in IE.


    jQuery("#" + id).closest(".t-palette").find("select").hover(function (event) {
      T5.console.debug("hover " + this.id);
      var $target = jQuery(event.target);
            if ($target.is("option")) {
                T5.console.debug("option = " + $target.text());
                this.title = $target.text();
            }
        });

Comment: Its not working for me .. i am trying ths same code. when i hover over on options it does't alert. .

Answer (score 6):

If you make a "listbox" type select box by adding a "size=x" attribute like this:

```
<select size="3">
   <option>...</option>
   <option>...</option>
</select>
```

The hover event will work on the option elements:

```
$('option').hover(function(){
     //code here
});
```

Comment: Tested working in safari and chrome - didn't test IE - http://jsfiddle.net/TJ6Fz/

Comment: great now remove size and test it again on chrome @A_funs

Comment: @Tarun Idk what your beef is here, my response says you need to include the size attribute for this to work, and when you do - it works...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround (quite decent I guess)-

- Use `mouseover` event to set the size of the select box equal to the no. of its children
- Use `mouseenter` event to get the options. `mouseenter` works on options perfectly when `size` attribute is there (we all know that now)
- Use `mouseout` event to set the size of the select box back to `1`, to get our normal select box back :)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pghpdbz/)