# Select Option Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `select` element, and I want to detect which `option` the user is hovering over. I am using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9144364) that ShankarSangoli has wrote but it is not working. I have tested in Chrome.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwc37/)

```
$("select").hover(function (e)
{
     var $target = $(e.target); 
     if($target.is('option')){
         alert($target.attr("id"));//Will alert id if it has id attribute
         alert($target.text());//Will alert the text of the option
         alert($target.val());//Will alert the value of the option
     }
});
```

Comment: As said in the question your refering to. Chrome does NOT support hover on `option` elements, neither does IE.

Comment: Is there another more viable solution?

Comment: I think you have to rethink your design for this one if you want Chrome or IE functionality. :(

Comment: Alrite, thanks. Can you post your response as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery-Select list option hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143924/jquery-select-list-option-hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you're trying to achieve is not availiable in Chrome nor IE yet.
This is pointed out in the question you're currently refering to.

As @purgatory 101 pointed out, a clever use of the combobox will allow you to "hook in" additional jquery which might allow you to alert(); on hover.

Just working of the source to combobox this would be a pointer in the right direction:

```
$('ul.ui-autocomplete ui-menu li').hover(function(){
    //do your stuff here.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

IE and Chrome do not support hover on option elements as [limelights](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441387/limelights) has pointed out. However, if you are already comfortable using jQuery you could try using the [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) it can use an underlying select but builds the options using ul and li elements.

Comment: Forgot about that completely! Nice one! :D

Comment: That is what I have always used whenever I have wanted better styling, more control or a searchable (autocomplete-style) list. There are a few quirks with doing the combobox, but nothing that is a deal-breaker...and it is nice since you can use it right on top of a native select.

Answer (score 1):

Your only way to accomplish this would be use use a `SELECT` replacement that uses HTML + JS + CSS instead of the native control.

Answer (score 0):

option:hover works in IE11 - woot!