# Change text to <option> when hovering over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

There is a nested `<select>`, and when you hover over one of the nested `<option>`, you need to change its text to match `ctisData2`. By default, the text is taken from `ctisData` for the `<option>` of the nested `<select>`.

```
<th><form class='lm_search_box'>
                        <div style='position: relative;'>
                            <select id='optSelect' class='lm_search_input' style='font-family: \"Roboto\"; font-size: 15px;'>
                                <option value=''>Select</option>
                                <option value='Option1'>Option1</option>
                                <option value='Option2'>Option2</option>
                                <option value='Option3'>Option3</option>
                            </select>
                            <select id='typeSelect' class='lm_search_input' style='font-family: \"Roboto\"; display: none;'>
                                <option value=''>Select</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                   </form>
                </th>\n";

                $head .= "<script>
                const ctisData = {
                  'Option1': ['Op11', 'Op12', 'Op13'],
                  'Option2': ['Op21', 'Op22', 'Op23'],
                  'Option3': ['Op31', 'Op32', 'Op33']
                };
                
                const ctisData2 = {
                  'Option1': ['Option11', 'Option12', 'Option13'],
                  'Option2': ['Option21', 'Option22', 'Option23'],
                  'Option3': ['Option31', 'Option32', 'Option33']
                };

                function do_select(select, options) {
                  select.innerHTML = '<option>Select</option>';
                  options.forEach(function(value) {
                    var z = document.createElement('option');
                    z.setAttribute('value', value);
                    z.innerText = value;
                    select.appendChild(z);
                  });
                }

                var sel_category = document.getElementById('optSelect');
                var sel_type = document.getElementById('typeSelect');

                sel_category.addEventListener('change', function() {
                  var selectedCategory = sel_category.value;
                  if (selectedCategory !== '') {
                    sel_type.style.display = 'block';
                    do_select(sel_type, ctisData[selectedCategory]);
                  } else {
                    sel_type.style.display = 'none';
                  }
                });

                sel_type.addEventListener('change', function() {
                  var selectedValue = sel_type.value;
                  if (selectedValue !== '') {
                    window.location.href = 'index.php?_search=' + selectedValue + '&action=search';
                  }
                });
            </script>
```

Added the following code but it doesn't work. The text does not change

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#optSelect option');
options.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        var category = sel_category.value;
        var index = Array.from(options).indexOf(this);
        var newOptionText = ctisData2[category][index];
        this.innerText = newOptionText;
    });
    option.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        var category = sel_category.value;
        var index = Array.from(options).indexOf(this);
        var originalOptionText = ctisData[category][index];
        this.innerText = originalOptionText;
    });
});
```

Maybe you need to add some css or some other solution? How to implement it? Help please.

There is such an option, but it does not work. What is the problem?

```
$head .= "<script>
        const ctisData = {
          'Option1': ['Op11', 'Op12', 'Op13'],
          'Option2': ['Op21', 'Op22', 'Op23'],
          'Option3': ['Op31', 'Op32', 'Op33']
        };
        
        const ctisData2 = {
          'Option1': ['Option11', 'Option12', 'Option13'],
          'Option2': ['Option21', 'Option22', 'Option23'],
          'Option3': ['Option31', 'Option32', 'Option33']
        };

        function do_select(select, options) {
          select.innerHTML = '<option>Select</option>';
          options.forEach(function(value) {
            var z = document.createElement('option');
            z.setAttribute('value', value);
            z.innerText = value;
            select.appendChild(z);
          });
        }

        var sel_category = document.getElementById('optSelect');
        var sel_type = document.getElementById('typeSelect');

        sel_category.addEventListener('change', function() {
          var selectedCategory = sel_category.value;
          if (selectedCategory !== '') {
            sel_type.style.display = 'block';
            do_select(sel_type, ctisData[selectedCategory]);
          } else {
            sel_type.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: That is, the dynamic change of the text in <option> will not work?

Comment: or you could use jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143924/jquery-select-list-option-hover

Comment: Yes, thank you. But how to use it in this code?

Comment: Look into the use of attribute size.

Comment: font-size? <select id='optSelect' class='lm_search_input' style='font-family: \"Roboto\"; font-size: 15px;'>

Comment: No, `size` attribute, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093469/1169519) in the post GrafiCode has linked. In your specific case, listen `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on the select element, not on the options.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't understand exactly how to change my code. Help me please.

Comment: $('#typeSelect').on('mouseenter', 'option', function() {
    var selectedCategory = $('#optSelect').val();
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).val(ctisData2[selectedCategory][index]);
});

$('#typeSelect').on('mouseleave', 'option', function() {
    var selectedCategory = $('#optSelect').val();
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).val(ctisData[selectedCategory][index]);
});  There is such an option, but it does not work

Comment: So how to implement it?