# onmouseover not working in option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple example

```html
<select>
  <option value="Hallo" onmouseover="alert('HAllo');">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

W3School says that the `onmouseover` Event is supported by the `option` tag as part of the standard event attributes in HTML. I am sure that it worked a few browser versions earlier but now no javascript is called.

It does not work with Vivaldi, chrome or firefox

**NOTE:** I do not use jquery. Thank you for not marking this question as a duplicate when the other linked question contains a technology I don't use.

Comment: `W3School says that` Consider looking for a more trustworthy site, such as MDN.

Comment: check the below links , useful info [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064011/select-option-hover-is-not-working-in-ie), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover)

Comment: So the "duplicate" says that I do have to use jquery?

Comment: This is not a duplicated question!

Comment: Thanks Reza Saadati. I already flagged CertainPerformance comment

Comment: @OtisOttington unfortunately, I cannot post an answer here but take a look at my code in JSFiddle. Most browsers do not support it as you already said but it works if the `size` of `select` is AT LEAST `2`. https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/p4t3rj85/47/